# Influxdb CLI differences between 1.8 to 2.3

Tags: command-line-interface, influxdb, telegraf, influxql

I have code to query data using CLI version 1.8.
now we upgrade to version 2.3, and the calls doesn’t work. I saw the syntax has changed dramatically, but wonder if there is some backward compatibility.

the call in version 1.8 is as follows (bat file):

```
SET start=%1

SET end=%2

cd “C:\Program Files\InfluxDB”

influx.exe -execute “use telegraf”

influx -database “telegraf” -execute “select mean(*) from win_cpu where time > ‘%start%’ AND time < ‘%end%’”
```

please let me know how to run this call in version 2.3.

thx in advance

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.3/query-data/influxql/
The very first paragraph says:

In InfluxDB 1.x, data is stored in databases and retention policies. In InfluxDB 2.3, data is stored in buckets. Because InfluxQL uses the 1.x data model, a bucket must be mapped to a database and retention policy (DBRP) before it can be queried using InfluxQL.
I'd suggest doing another round with the docs.

Comment: I did another round and find solution. however it looks strange CLI calls changed. I would assume for backward compatibility all calls in CLI would stay the same.

Comment: link to documentation: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.3/reference/api/influxdb-1x/query/